# Comparison of cases available via Apple's case program

Tags: iphone, accessories

I'm trying to decide which case to choose via [Apple's case program](http://www.apple.com/iphone/case-program/).

Are there any side by side physical comparisons of the cases available? All I have been able to find is speculative information, gleaned from marketing material.

Feel free to provide your findings if you have one of the cases already.

Comment: (Personally I don't fancy the bumpers, or any of the patterned cases, so it's down to the Incase Snap Case vs Belkin Shield Micra, I can't see much difference between them. But it would be good to find a comparison of all)

Comment: Program ends September 10. So choosing top voted question as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an article like that here

http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/backstage/comments/apple-iphone-4-case-program-here-are-the-best-worst-picks/

Their top pick is the [Speck PixelSkin HD](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/reviews/entry/speck-pixelskin-hd-for-iphone-4/)

Answer (score 0):

I took the plunge and went with the [Belkin Shield Micra](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B003R6U4M8?ie=UTF8&tag=mophosandphot-21&linkCode=as2&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=B003R6U4M8), which arrived today.

It's a pretty basic and fairly cheap feeling, all-in-one, hard plastic casing. It's pretty thin and feels fairly brittle - a hard knock would probably break the plastic.

I *wouldn't* have paid full price for it.

However, it does protect the back and sides from scratches and the 'deathgrip' (I *assume*, as it wasn't occuring beforehand for me either). It also allows access to all the slots, buttons and lenses and 'slides' easily into your pocket.

It's also very understated (completely clear apart from small etched logo) - which is what I wanted.

[image: Photo of Belkin Shield Micra case]

Comment: Blue-tac in bottom right is an optional extra ;)